# How to get out from under parent directory's git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm not sure what I did to start it, but somehow now every time I create a new angular project in a folder inside of "VSCodeProjects" (where I put my new projects), it seems to think there is already a git file set up in a parent directory (perhaps VSCodeProjects itself?) and I get the message "Directory is already under version control".  And then when I open root directory for the project, I see in VS code changes tab I see a "too many changes" message, where it tells me it will only display the first 10,000(!) changes.

The last time this happened I was somehow able to disconnect the project from the giant git and start a new one just for this project (which is what I want), but don't quite remember how I did that, and I would somehow like do whatever necessary to stop this parent git from being assigned to every new project I create. with `ng new'

Can somebody explain what's going on, and how I can stop it?

Comment: find the `.git` folder in any of the parent folders

Comment: Do I need to delete the git files in parent folder it in order for angular to stop automatically pushing new projects into it?

Comment: you want to get rid of the already under SCM warning, so get rid of the offending `.git` folder

Comment: I get that, but I'm not that's the only git for some project that's just been hanging around for a couple of years.  It probably doesn't matter but . . .

Comment: then create sibling folders with their own `.git` folder